# Nginx virtual host not working

Tags: php, linux, nginx

I'm hosting a PHP system on my localhost, I created `index.php` in the `/var/www/html` like this:

```
// /var/www/html/index.php
<?php
phpinfo();
```

And when I access `localhost:80` it's showing up my PHP configurations info.

But when I cloned `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/superstore` and changed `server_name` it's not working after `sudo service nginx restart`, even `sudo service nginx status` is returning success.

My nginx config (`/etc/nginx/sites-available/superstore`) is like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name superstore.dev;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

My PHP version:
[image: PHP version]

Nginx status after restart:
[image: Nginx status after restart]

I added this virtual host to my `/etc/hosts` like this:

```
127.0.0.1   superstore.dev
```

But when I try to access `superstore.dev` it's returning this error to me:
[image: This site can't be reached error print screen]

I installed PHP and Nginx by following command on Ubuntu 16:

```
sudo apt install nginx php7.0-fpm -y
```

And I'm sure that I already symbolic linked `superstore` config file to `sites-enabled` folder.

Why my virtual host is not working?

Comment: What are the contents of `/etc/nginx/sites-available/superstore`?

Comment: @arielnmz I just updated the description, the only one nginx config content in the description is from `superstore`

Comment: What do the php and nginx logs say?

Comment: I checked `/var/log/nginx/access.log` and `error.log`, both of them are not being changed when I access the page.

Comment: I already tried most of fix that I found in the Google, but it's still not resolving my problem

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Apache config scheme, folder `sites-available` is supposed to contain all your config files, even the ones you don't want to run.

There is a second folder, `sites-enabled`, that contains symlinks to the config files you want to run.

To create the symlink run `ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/superstore /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` and then `service nginx reload`

For more info see answer https://serverfault.com/a/424456/240702

Comment: Actually my `superstore` config file is already linked to `sites-enabled` folder, but it's still not working